# Patch K8s Custom Resource with @kubernetes/client-node

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, istio

I'm building Istio/K8s-based platform for controlling traffic routing with NodeJS. I need to be able to programmatically modify Custom Resources and I'd like to use the [@kubernetes/node-client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript) for that. I wasn't able to find the right API for accessing Custome Resources in docs and the repo. Am I missing something? Thx in adv.

EDIT: When using CustomObjectApi.patchNamespacedCustomObject function, I'm getting the following error back from K8s API:

`message: 'the body of the request was in an unknown format - accepted media types include: application/json-patch+json, application/merge-patch+json, application/apply-patch+yaml', reason: 'UnsupportedMediaType', code: 415`

My Code:

```js
const k8sYamls = `${path.resolve(path.dirname(__filename), '..')}/k8sYamls`
const vServiceSpec = read(`${k8sYamls}/${service}/virtual-service.yaml`)
const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig()
kc.loadFromDefault()
const client = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.CustomObjectsApi)
const result = await client.patchNamespacedCustomObject(vServiceSpec.apiVersion.split('/')[0], vServiceSpec.apiVersion.split('/')[1], namespace, 'virtualservices', vServiceSpec.metadata.name, vServiceSpec)
```

virtual-service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: message-service
spec:
  hosts:
  - message-service
  http:
  - name: 'production'
    route:
    - destination:
        host: message-service
      weight: 100
    retries:
      attempts: 3
      perTryTimeout: 2s
      retryOn: 5xx
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was using the wrong type for the `body` object in that method. I got it to work following [this example](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/master/examples/patch-example.js).

```js
const patch = [
  {
    "op": "replace",
    "path":"/metadata/labels",
    "value": {
      "foo": "bar"
    }
  }
];
const options = { "headers": { "Content-type": k8s.PatchUtils.PATCH_FORMAT_JSON_PATCH}};
k8sApi.patchNamespacedPod(res.body.items[0].metadata.name, 'default', patch, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, options)
  .then(() => { console.log("Patched.")})
  .catch((err) => { console.log("Error: "); console.log(err)});
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the edit queue is full for the accepted answer I'm going to provide a working example and more thorough answer here using `patchNamespacedCustomObject`:

Here are some helpful links:

- [patchNamespacedCustomObject Docs](https://kubernetes-client.github.io/javascript/classes/customobjectsapi.customobjectsapi-1.html#patchnamespacedcustomobject)
- Your **patch** object should be an array of [this object](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/935bca2df1da5fa8f054252afa4b05ec7f9dc26b/staging/src/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/endpoints/handlers/patch.go#L357-L362)
- The `op` field should be [one of these](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/935bca2df1da5fa8f054252afa4b05ec7f9dc26b/vendor/github.com/evanphx/json-patch/patch.go#L808-L820)

```js
import * as k8s from "@kubernetes/client-node";
import { CustomObjectsApi, KubeConfig } from "@kubernetes/client-node";

export async function patchCustomResource(newValue: any) {
  const kc: KubeConfig = new k8s.KubeConfig();
  kc.loadFromDefault();
  
  const custObjApi: CustomObjectsApi = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.CustomObjectsApi);
  
  const objectName = 'your-object';
  const options = { "headers": { "Content-type": k8s.PatchUtils.PATCH_FORMAT_JSON_PATCH}};
  const group = 'your-group'; // found in the CRD
  const version = 'v1'; // found in the CRD
  const plural = 'object-plural'; // found in the CRD
  const namespace = `your-namespace`;

  // this will replace the value at `"/spec/path/to/modify"` with the contents of `newValue`
  const patch = [{
    "op": "replace",
    "path":"/spec/path/to/modify", 
    "value": newValue
  }];

  try {
    await custObjApi.patchNamespacedCustomObject(group, version, namespace, plural, objectName, patch, undefined, undefined, undefined, options);
    console.log(`Successfully updated custom resource`);
  } catch (error) {
    const {body} = error;
    console.log(body.message);
  }
}
```

I urge anyone to spend some time on the [CustomObjectsAPI](https://kubernetes-client.github.io/javascript/classes/customobjectsapi.customobjectsapi-1.html) docs to get more familiar with the available methods. The docs are dense but it's at least worth it to glance over method names.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `patchClusterCustomObject` or `patchNamespacedCustomObject` methods, depending on whether the given object is namespaced or not, of the [`customObjectsApi`](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/6c5a58f51b8cdb01c59cbd5b433013beb4940df2/src/gen/api/customObjectsApi.ts).

Comment: When using CustomObjectApi, I'm getting the following error back from K8s API: `message: 'the body of the request was in an unknown format - accepted media types include: application/json-patch+json, application/merge-patch+json, application/apply-patch+yaml', reason: 'UnsupportedMediaType', code: 415`

Comment: @AleksanderNowak Could you try it with `replaceNamespacedCustomObject` as an alternative? Just to see if it works.

Comment: Of course. It gives another error: `virtualservices.networking.istio.io "message-service" is invalid: metadata.resourceVersion: Invalid value: 0x0: must be specified for an update`. Attaching my VirtualService spec above.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually [several types of patch formats supported by the Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#patch-and-apply) (and therefore the [JavaScript client API](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/master/src/patch.ts)), including:

- `application/json-patch+json` (`k8s.PatchUtils.PATCH_FORMAT_JSON_PATCH`)
- `application/merge-patch+json` (`k8s.PatchUtils.PATCH_FORMAT_JSON_MERGE_PATCH`)
- `application/strategic-merge-patch+json` (`k8s.PatchUtils.PATCH_FORMAT_STRATEGIC_MERGE_PATCH`);
- `application/apply-patch+yaml` (`k8s.PatchUtils.PATCH_FORMAT_APPLY_YAML`);

The type of patch format dictates the expected format of the `body` parameter when calling a corresponding "patch" method. For instance, if you want to alter the `finalizers` of a namespace custom resource, you could indeed provide a body that looks like previous examples by using the `application/json-patch+json` encoding:

```js
// This body is in the format expected by 'application/json-patch+json'
const body = [{
  "op": "replace",
  "path": "/metadata/finalizers",
  "value": updatedFinalizers
}];

// Specify 'application/json-patch+json' content type
const options = { headers: { 'Content-Type': k8s.PatchUtils.PATCH_FORMAT_JSON_PATCH } };

await custObjApi.patchNamespacedCustomObject(group, version, namespace,
  plural, objectName, body, undefined, undefined, undefined, options);
```

However, you can also utilize the 'application/merge-patch+json' option and perform the same update as follows:

```js
// This body is in the format expected by 'application/merge-patch+json'
const body = {
  metadata: {
    finalizers: updatedFinalizers
  }
};

// Specify 'application/merge-patch+json' content type
const options = { headers: { 'Content-Type': k8s.PatchUtils.PATCH_FORMAT_JSON_MERGE_PATCH } };

await custObjApi.patchNamespacedCustomObject(group, version, namespace,
  plural, objectName, body, undefined, undefined, undefined, options);
```

Answer (score -1):

After fighting through endless body-parsing errors using [@kubernetes/node-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kubernetes/client-node), I opted to install [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/) on my NodeJS workers and use [shell.js](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs) to run it with.

My conclusion is that the [@kubernetes/node-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kubernetes/client-node) is buggy when used with Istio Custom Resources, but didn't want to spend time debugging exactly what's wrong. I will post the Github Issue about it in their repo soon.